# Changing value of bool at random time within limits

Tags: c#, random, boolean

What I am trying to write is a piece of code that will change the value of a bool from true to false and visa versa at a random time between say 1 and 3 seconds. I've tried many methods using random. etc and attempting to set a timer that resets but it just doesn't click. I'm using c# which I'm quite new to so I'm not sure if this is a simple trick or something more complex.
Any forums or videos are much appreciated anyhow.

//

I tried using the code provided by Matthew but it threw up a lot of errors. I am using unity 5 so that may be the problem.
Anyhow I have tried using the following code.

> ```
> bool switchSpawning = false;
> void Update () {
>     if (switchSpawning == false) {
>         transform.position = spawnPosition;
>     } else if (switchSpawning == true) {
>         transform.position = spawnPosition2;
>     }
> }
>     void Switching (){ // works in void update - runs at every frame
>     System.Random rnd = new System.Random ();
>     int num = rnd.Next(0,10); //random number between 0 and 10
>     if (num < 5) {
>         switchSpawning = false;
>         Debug.Log("False");
>     } 
>     else if (num > 5) {
>         switchSpawning = true;
>         Debug.Log("True");
>     }
> }
> ```

If I place the code in void Switching into void Update its works just as i want it to just every frame obviously not at a random time.

Comment: Show us your code. Also, is this winforms? If so, you may need a separate thread depending on your UI requirements. What are your UI requirements?

Comment: What did you actually try? Show us your code :) Anyhow: call the randomizer every second and roll a dice for the new value. Sometimes it will change, somteimes not - though then the length might be possibly much longer than 3 seconds.

Comment: I haven't much code for it, that's the problem. I looked through forums and videos and they seem to use random numbers generator and then use if statements to change the bool depending on the number. However I don't understand how to incorporate the time aspect into it. Is there any useful websites you know of?

Comment: What about just picking a random index from an array of spawns? Useful because you can write utility code to pull a random item from a `List<T>` and use it all over your code!

Comment: I can see how that have the same effect with the benefit of having my code considerably shorter. However I'm still unsure of the timing issue I'm having.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a timer to do this.

First, use a random number generator to generate a number of milliseconds between 1000 and 3000:

```
int millseconds = new Random().Next(1000, 3001);
```

Then create a timer that will fire after that many milliseconds, and for its action specify some code that will set the boolean value:

```
var callback = new Timer(dummy => { value = true; }, null, millseconds, -1);
```

Note that the `dummy` argument is not used. The action that sets the variable to true is `{ value = true; }`, which assumes that there is a bool variable called `value` in scope.

Also note that the resolution of this timer is not very high - probably no more than 10-20ms, but for a random interval that probably doesn't matter.

Putting this together into a simple console application gives the following:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            bool value = false;

            int millseconds = new Random().Next(1000, 3001);
            var callback    = new Timer(dummy => { value = true; }, null, millseconds, -1);

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }

            callback.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```